# Assign different bottom-border color active class with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have created an active class that toggles when a user clicks on 3 buttons - "overview, structure, surface". The initial color of the bottom-border color is set to purple. So when a user clicks on any of these buttons, the selected button gets a purple bottom-border color. My goal now is to implement a different bottom-border color for when a user selects a link in the nav bar for these 3 buttons. I have set the active class to the first button in my html markup. I have code written that selects the active class and if "x" is clicked, set the color to "y". So the first button gets the bottom-border color. When I click on the following button, the bottom-border color is still purple. Main goal: Set a different bottom-border color for 3 buttons for all the links in the nav bar + toggle the active class among the buttons.

```
// html markup
  <div class="mobile__CTA">
        <button id="overview-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn active">
          OVERVIEW
        </button>
        <button id="structure-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">STRUCTURE</button>
        <button id="surface-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">SURFACE</button>
      </div>

// selecting all btns
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile__CTA--btn");

// looping through each btn and toggling the action class
callToActionBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    callToActionBtns.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});

// mercury btn function 

mercuryBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch(file)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error("Error");
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      let dataInfo = data;

      planetImg.src = dataInfo[0].images.planet;
      planetName.innerHTML = dataInfo[0].name;
      planetDesc.innerHTML = dataInfo[0].overview.content;
      wikiSource.href = dataInfo[0].overview.source;
      rotateTime.innerHTML = dataInfo[0].rotation;
      revolutionTime.innerHTML = dataInfo[0].revolution;
      radiusTime.innerHTML = dataInfo[0].radius;
      averageTime.innerHTML = dataInfo[0].temperature;
    });
  document.querySelector(".active").style.borderBottom =
    "5px solid rgb(65,158,187)";
});
```

[image: When clicked on Mercury..bottom-border active color is set to lightblue]

[image: If a user clicks on the following button, there is this bug.]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly all you should have to do is give each of your buttons an individual active state style using CSS like so:

```js
// selecting all btns
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile__CTA--btn");

// looping through each btn and toggling the action class
callToActionBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    callToActionBtns.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#overview-btn.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid purple;
}

#structure-btn.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid teal;
}

#surface-btn.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile__CTA">
  <button id="overview-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn active">
    OVERVIEW
  </button>
  <button id="structure-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">STRUCTURE</button>
  <button id="surface-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">SURFACE</button>
</div>
```

That will allow you to style each element with a different color border when it is clicked on or made active.

A note about what you appear to be trying with the last line of your JS. You are selecting the element that has the `.active` class at that time and adding a border to that element, not changing the `.active` class which is why your border is not disappearing when you click on other buttons.